# Why is my Vector size 0?

Tags: java

As you can see in the screenshot, `new_mean`'s capacity is 0 eventhough I've created it with an initial capacity of 2 therefore I'm getting index out of bounds exception.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Update: Here's the code

```
private static Vector<Double> get_new_mean(
        Tuple<Set<Vector<Double>>, Vector<Double>> cluster,
        Vector<Double> v, boolean is_being_added) {
    Vector<Double> previous_mean = cluster.y;
    int n = previous_mean.size(), set_size = cluster.x.size();
    Vector<Double> new_mean = new Vector<Double>(n);
    if (is_being_added) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double temp = set_size * previous_mean.get(i);
            double updated_mean = (temp + v.get(i)) / (set_size + 1);
            new_mean.set(i, updated_mean);
        }
    } else {
        if (set_size > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                double temp = set_size * previous_mean.get(i);
                double updated_mean = (temp - v.get(i)) / (set_size - 1);
                new_mean.set(i, updated_mean);
            }
        } else {
            new_mean = null;
        }
    }
    return new_mean;
}
```

Comment: Please, post the related code, not just an image of it.

Comment: Two minutes please, let us take our glasses to see this microscopic picture. Please post your code here as text.

Comment: The text on image is too small to read. Post code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capacity is the total number of elements you **could** store. 
Size is the number of elements you have actually stored.

In your code, there is nothing stored in the Vector, so you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when you try to access element 0.

Comment: Funny how no one was able to read the code yet they knew this was the right answer. Thanks, seems like I've used set instead of add.

Comment: It was redeable if you opened the image in another window.

Comment: @Shmoopy Unfortunately question downvotes are sometimes catchy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set(int, object)` to change an **EXISTING** element. Use `add(int, object)` to add a **NEW** element.

This is explained in the javadoc for `Vector`s. `elementCount` should be 0 (it's empty) and `capacityIncrement` is 0 by default, and is only relevant if you're going to go over the limit you specified (2).

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill your `Vector` with `null` values to make it's size equal to the capacity. Capacity is an optimization hint for the collection, it makes no change to the collection usage. Collection will automatically grow as you add elements to it and capacity will increase. So initializing with a higher capacity would requires less expansions and less memory allocations.